# How to integrate multiple plugins in tinymce?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have tried this simple code to try tinyMCE. It is working fine. Here the problem is when I am trying to add multiple plugin it is not working. Here I have used tinymce CDN. Here is the code

```
<script>tinymce.init({selector:'textarea',
        plugins: "code",
        plugins: "image"
        });</script>
<body><textarea></textarea></body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using plugins twice. I suggest you do it this way:

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector:'textarea',
        plugins: "code image"
    });
</script>
<body><textarea></textarea></body>
```

Comment: Thank you @ ketchupisred

Comment: @KaziShahadatHossain Sure thing. Please mark as solved if it worked for you.

Comment: You click the outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
tinymce.init({
        selector:'textarea',
        plugins: "code image"
    });
```